# How to remove all datas from centos

Tags: centos

I wanna remove all data of the Linux server and want to do replace, 
Could you recommend the most suitable command?
How to remove?

Answer (score 3):

Pick another distro of your choice, download/burn the iso, boot off of it, install, making sure to erase all existing partitions in the process. If you're more paranoid than that and want to ensure that the data totally, completely erased - so much so that a forensic investigator couldn't recover it - then check out [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/).

Comment: Thank you for answering!.
Do you have another solution with no cd?

Comment: You're looking to completely re-install, correct? If so, I'm not sure there's a good way of doing that without some way of booting another OS (in this case, the livecd). Lemme guess, this is a dedicated server somewhere that you don't have physical access to. Do you have access to any remote management tools or LOM cards on this server?

Answer (score 1):

yum install -y gparted then you can format active partitions erase !! it is gui and you dont need to run any command for.